# CKFinder Upload Permissions Issue

Tags: permissions, ckeditor, ckfinder

Afternoon,

I have been working with CKEditor and CKFinder for the last few days and it all worked locally. Once I put it live in all aspects it worked except when attempting to upload a .pdf file to the server via the Link -> Upload tab.

The error that I receive is "The requested resource type is not valid". I have set the folders that it is uploading to, to 777 and I have made sure that the Resource type of Files also allows for the extensions of .pdf in config.php of CKFinder.

This error is stopping me from completion of my project and I really am out of things to try any ideas/ work arounds would be brilliant.

One possible solution was to use KCFinder which I was told would work but my boss said that was not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been an out dated version of CKFinder and I fiddled with the config file and made sure that the $baseUrl and $baseDir followed the rules in the comments. Prior to that I think my $baseUrl did not have the '/' at the beginning of it and now does. The problem lies in the config.php file in CKFinder for anyone else that has the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the message is "the resource type is not valid" then it's not a permissions issue, but instead that you have renamed the resource types and so it doesn't initialize properly.

If you already have a license to CKFinder you should post this kind of questions at the forums or through the support channel.